# python - how to check if a variable is a function?

Tags: python, function

I have a variable definite with a "def", it's a function :

```
o = [<function result at 0x7f222138c7d0>]
type(o) = <type 'function'>
```

How to integer a `if` in my code ?

```
if type(o) == 'function':  # pseudocode
   print 'Found!'
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little hard to decipher - it appears you want to ask how to check if a variable is a function? (Rather than 'defining' one).

Comment: Yes, it's the good title for my question. I will edit it.

Comment: `callable(o)` works fine. Thanks all

Comment: I have a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906449/python-how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-gtk-gdk-pixbufloader):