# python - how to check if a variable is 'gtk.gdk.PixbufLoader'?

Tags: python, variables, gtk

I would like to know if it's possible to check if a variable is this type:

```
<type 'gtk.gdk.PixbufLoader'>
```

with a line like:

```
if type(var) == 'gtk.gdk.PixbufLoader':  # pseudocode
   print "Found!"
```

Thanks

Comment: It is with noting that checking the type of variables in python is often a sign of a design issue, as Pythonic code shouldn't usually require it. Sometimes it is unavoidable, but if you start doing it a lot, you should rethink your design. Python is a duck typed language - what type it is isn't meant to be important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(var, gtk.gdk.PixbufLoader):
    print 'Found!'
```